# Timeout when adding mozillateam/ppa repository

Tags: apt, kubuntu, firefox, ppa, timeout

I'm using Kubuntu 22.04, apt update and upgrade work fine.

I'm following https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04 to uninstall Firefox snap and install from apt, but when I add mozillateam/ppa it hangs for a few minutes then I get timeout error:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 364, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 347, in main
    shortcut = handler(source, **shortcut_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuts.py", line 40, in shortcut_handler
    return handler(shortcut, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 82, in __init__
    if self.lpppa.publish_debug_symbols:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 120, in lpppa
    self._lpppa = self.lpteam.getPPAByName(name=self.ppaname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 107, in lpteam
    self._lpteam = self.lp.people(self.teamname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 98, in lp
    self._lp = login_func("%s.%s" % (self.__module__, self.__class__.__name__),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 494, in login_anonymously
    return cls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 230, in __init__
    super(Launchpad, self).__init__(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 472, in __init__
    self._wadl = self._browser.get_wadl_application(self._root_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 447, in get_wadl_application
    response, content = self._request(url, media_type=wadl_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 389, in _request
    response, content = self._request_and_retry(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 359, in _request_and_retry
    response, content = self._connection.request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1725, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 144, in _request
    response, content = super(LaunchpadOAuthAwareHttp, self)._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 184, in _request
    return super(RestfulHttp, self)._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1441, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1363, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1153, in connect
    sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

Is it something wrong on my end that I must fix?

Comment: Did you change something with python like your default python version?

Comment: No, I just upgraded apt libs.

Comment: I'm unable to find what it's trying to connect to. If I had a host I could make connection tests to figure why it's timing out.

Comment: See updated answer below. It should be trying to connect to `http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu` or `lanuchpad.net` but it also downloads a key. It might be a DNS or IPV6 issue if that is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other users report the problem is fixed if you install the `python-is-python3` package.

First, update the system:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Next, install:

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

This creates a symlink for python3 so that when you or the system executes `python`, it will link to `python3`.

I believe this was disabled by default after the full switch to `python3` to allow backwards compatibility for systems that need a default `python2` linked with `python`. But for most people, we need it linked to python3 as python2 was deprecated a while ago.

Then, proceed with the PPA installation instructions.

---

If that doesn't work, it might be a network issue. The ppa is at `http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu`.

If pinging `launchpad.net` returns nothing, you might be able to [disable IPV6 to resolve the issue](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474534&p=14101831#post14101831).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it keeps giving timeout. I also tried to manually symlink python to python3 and it also didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I added a quick log on python file that's generating the stacktrace, it tries to connect to api.launchpad.net. It resolves to 2620:2d:4000:1001::8003, which is timing out. I figured it also resolves to 185.125.189.224 which works.

I added it to /etc/hosts and now it works!